# How to export result of point_metrics() in lidR?

Tags: r, lidr

I have las files along coastal areas which include multiple flights. Usually I use both water and ground when normalizing but this data has 2 things to overcome. The first has ground at a lower level than water due to tides. The second is a problem because one flight classified vegetation as water. To help solve this (a quick attempt at ground classification didn't quite work), I want to extract water and ground, and then use point_metrics() to get the minimum value within a small neighbourhood. The idea is to use this minimum value as ground during normalization. How can I export the results of point_metrics() data table to a raster or las file (it has pointId & V1)?

[![profile of las with classification][1]][1]

```
library(raster)
setwd('D:/test/las')
las <- readLAS('579_4998_201801.las', filter = "-keep_class 2 9")
lasmin <- point_metrics(las, func = ~min(Z), k = 2, r = 1)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bsmC.png
```

Comment: I messed up this question and edited it after posting (sorry about that). I tried to convert the output of lasmin to a LAS file `las2 = LAS(lasmin, las@header)` but the xy coordinates are gone. In the end, I think I should reclassify using classify_ground. I will try and edit the code above but hope I don't confuse things more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of options depending on what you really want to do.

You can keep only the points with min Z that way

```r
library(lidR)
f = system.file("extdata", "Topography.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(f, filter = "-keep_class 2 9")
min = point_metrics(las, func = ~list(minZ = min(Z)), k = 2, r = 1)
boo = min$minZ == las$Z                    
gnd = las[boo]
```

If you want to get XYZ there is an option for that:

```r
min = point_metrics(las, func = ~list(minZ = min(Z)), k = 2, r = 1, xyz = TRUE)
```

If you want to reclassify the points based on the output of `point_metrics()` this is also doable but a little bit harder.

Comment: This works well, thanks. In the end I will use classify_ground() because it is safer. But point_metrics with x,y will be useful later on.